# Converting multiple if-else statements to case statements with more than boolean statements

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I have the following vectors that getting different entries based on another array.

- `PIP_ID`
- `SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS`
- `MPX_KIT_IDS`

Depending on the content of those I am creating different files using `if` statements/rules. For example:

```
if [ $PIP_ID == 8 ]; then   
    EXTENSION="ATLAS_"
fi
if [[ $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS == 81 ]] || [[ $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS == 86 ]]; then
    EXTENSION="SmartSeq3_"
fi
if [[ $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS == 61 ]] || [[ $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS == 72 ]] || [[ $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS == 102]] || [[ $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS == 84 ]] ; then  
    EXTENSION="scRNAv3_"
fi
if ([[ $MPX_KIT_IDS == 89 ]] || [[ $MPX_KIT_IDS == 91 ]] || [[ $MPX_KIT_IDS ==  92 ]] || [[ $MPX_KIT_IDS == 93 ]]) && [[ SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS != 105 ]] ; then
    EXTENSION="AGENTtrim_"
fi
if [[ $MPX_KIT_IDS == 17 ]] || [[ $MPX_KIT_IDS == 27 ]] || [[ $MPX_KIT_IDS == 53 ]]; then   
    EXTENSION="miRNA_"
        fi
```

Note that the one that creates the `AGENTtrim_` has multiple OR combined with && statements grouped with parenthesis.

How can I turn those into a more simpler, more elegant solution using `case`? I do not know how to combine all the 3 variables into one, since the one that creates the `AGENTtrim_` gets info from 2 independent variables.

Comment: But... writing one case from that is not equivalent. And one `fi` is missing.

Comment: When `$PIP_ID == 8` and `$SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS == 81`, the EXTENSION will be "SmartSeq3_". Are you sure that the first match can be ignored when another match is found?

Comment: @WalterA the cases (database entries do not contradict themselves. The `PID_ID =8` will not be used in parallel with other options. But, your comment is valid. I guess a simple if PID_ID == 8 else all other cases can fix a future problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To be honest I do not know how to combine all the 3 variables into one

You can just put them together with a separator. For example, assuming there will be no commas in values, just pick a comma as separator and do a string:

```
shopt -s extglob  

case "$PIP_ID,$SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS,$MPX_KIT_IDS" in
8,*)                           EXTENSION="ATLAS_" ;;
*,81,*|*,86,*)                 EXTENSION="SmartSeq3_" ;;
*,61,*|*,72,*|*,102,*|*,85,*)  EXTENSION="scRNAv3_" ;;
# with extended glob shopt -s extglob
*,!(105),@(89|91))             EXTENSION="AGENTtrim_" ;;
*,17|*,27|*,53)                EXTENSION="miRNA_" ;;
# etc...
esac
```

Comment: can I get the `shopt -s extglob` into the script? There are two servers, one has the extended glob activated the other not.

Comment: ? Just write `shopt -s extglob` in the script. Note that you _have to_ be running Bash, not anything else, this is specific specifically to Bash shell.

Comment: our servers only use bash

Answer (score 3):

Converting it to a case statement would be ugly.  You can simplify it by using extended pattern matching.

```
if [[ $MPX_KIT_IDS == @(89|91|92|93) && $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS != 105 ]]; then
    EXTENSION="AGENTtrim_"
elif [[ $MPX_KIT_IDS == @(17|27|53) ]]; then
    EXTENSION="miRNA_"
elif [[ $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS == @(81|86) ]]; then
    EXTENSION="SmartSeq3_"
elif [[ $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS == @(61|72|102|84) ]]; then
    EXTENSION="scRNAv3_"
elif [[ $PIP_ID == 8 ]]; then
    EXTENSION="ATLAS_"
fi
```

Comment: Is this also a portable solution (provided that the extended glob is active)?
In addition why it will be ugly? I find that the case statement might work better when those conditions are changing and expanding.

Comment: @sunta3iouxos No it isn't portable. Case statements only does single inclusive or expressions so you would have to resort to second level condition hacks.  You can't beg its functionality to work differently,

Answer (score 1):

Make use of functions which name can clarify the rule.

```
atlas_pip() {
  [[ $1 == 8 ]]
}

smart_id() {
  [[ $1 =~ ^(61|72)$ ]]
}

rna_id() {
  [[ $1 =~ ^(61|72|102|84)$ ]]
}

agent_id() {
  [[ $1 =~ ^(89|91|92|93)$ ]]
}

mirna_id() {
  [[ $1 =~ ^(17|27|53)$ ]]
}

atlas_pip $PIP_ID          && EXTENSION="ATLAS_"
smart_id  $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS && EXTENSION="SmartSeq3_"
rna_id    $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS && EXTENSION="scRNAv3_"
agent_id  $MPX_KIT_IDS && $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS != 105 && EXTENSION="AGENTtrim_"
mirna_id  $MPX_KIT_IDS     && EXTENSION="miRNA_"
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I am not an avid "functions" user and they trouble me a bit. But this one seems quite promising. Especially if I need to expand or change entries.

Comment: A function performs some actions like other script. Input is with parameters that can e addresses as `$1`, `$2`, .... With `exit 0` a function returns "true" (the `$?`). When you want to return data, this is normally done using stdout . Example: `divide() { (( $# != 2 )) && return 1; (( $2 == 0 )) && return 2; echo $(( $1 / $2)); return 0; }`.
The functions here are strange: they return true when the condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

*IF* your nonexclusive `if` statements cannot *overwrite* because a later condition is also met but has a higher priority, then this *nested* `case` structure should should create the same effective logic.

```
case $PIP_ID in
8) EXTENSION="ATLAS_"       ;;
*) case $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS in                                 # PIP_ID is NOT 8
          8[16]) EXTENSION="SmartSeq3_" ;;
   61|72|102|84) EXTENSION="scRNAv3_"   ;;
              *) case $MPX_KIT_IDS in
                  [12]7|53) EXTENSION="miRNA_"     ;;
                 89|9[123]) case $SAMPLE_TYPE_IDS in
                            105) : nothing to do        ;;  # sets NO extension if it gets to this
                              *) EXTENSION="AGENTtrim_" ;;
                            esac                   ;;
                 esac                   ;;
   esac                     ;;
esac
```

Comment: This is a bit complicated, too many nested cases that seem as unnecessary

Comment: I agree, but as an exercise it answers the OP.